# What IoC/DI library for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, windows-phone-8

Is there any IoC/DI library that works with Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using Ninject, and it's really good. Take a look [here](http://www.ninject.org/). Works for WP7 and WP8, quite light-weight (though I didn't make direct comparisons with other solutions).

Answer (score 1):

[Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) works well with WP8, as well as desktop. 
I don't think it works for WP7 however; should legacy WP7 support ever be an issue.
It's Microsoft Patterns & Practices and is OSS.
Needless to say it integrates very well with any of the other P&P libraries.